# How to minimize a maximum of a function of 2 parameters with R

Tags: r, self-study, optimization, derivative

I need to maximize wrt **x** and minimize wrt $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ the ratio (I will call it **f**) between the density of a standard normal and a double exponential distribution. So my goal is to find $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$

I write the function:

$ f(x) = \frac{exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2*pi}}{(\alpha/2)*exp(-\alpha * |x|)} $

By taking its derivative w.r.t to **x**, I find that **f** is maximum in **x=**$\pm \boldsymbol{\alpha}$. Now I compute **f(**$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$**)** = **f(-** $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$**)** = $\sqrt{2/π} * exp(α^2 /2) /α$  and I minimize it by taking its derivative in $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$. I will find $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=\pm$**1** as a result I was looking for.

How can I find $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ with **R**? I built the function but I cannot find a way to solve this kind of problem.

```
f<-function(param) {
x<-param[1]
alpha<-param[2]
fn<-(exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi))/((alpha/2)*exp(-alpha*abs(x))) 
return(fn)
}
```

Comment: Look at ?optim in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of $f(x,\alpha)$ maximimised with respect to $x$ becomes a new function $g(\alpha)$ that only depends on $\alpha$.  If I understand your problem correctly you then want to minimise $g(\alpha)$ with respect to $\alpha$.  Here is how you could do this numerically in R.

```
dlaplace <- function(x,alpha) 
  alpha/2*exp(-alpha*abs(x))

f <- function(x,alpha) 
  dnorm(x)/dlaplace(x,alpha)

g <- function(alpha) 
  optimize(f,c(0,10),alpha=alpha,maximum=TRUE)$objective

optimize(g,c(0,10),maximum=FALSE)
```